# Prevent specific USB Mass Storage mount with udev on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, mount, usb, modem

On Ubuntu 10.04, I have a USB 3G dongle which presents itself initially as a USB Mass Storage device with Windows drivers. [usb_modeswitch](http://www.draisberghof.de/usb_modeswitch/) can be used to get it to present itself as a modem, but the mass storage device still auto-mounts itself every time I plug it in as well. This is just an irritation/ugliness, not a serious problem, but I'm wondering if it's possible to write a udev rule to stop the device mounting, by filesystem name/UUID? I searched around, but couldn't find an example of such a rule.

Comment: well, I have used usb_modeswitch for exactly that. A yum info usb_modeswitch tells me: "USB Modeswitch brings up your datacard into operational mode. When plugged in they identify themselves as cdrom and present some non-Linux compatible installation files. This tool deactivates this cdrom-devices and enables the real communication device. It supports most devices built and sold by Huawei, T-Mobile, Vodafone, Option, ZTE, Novatel." I do not use it any more because my laptop has an integrated sim, but it worked fine for me in the past. So maybe it has to be properly set?

Comment: So I am using usb_modeswitch (correctly, AFAIK), but I still see the USB mass storage mounted also. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: apparently the udev rules in your system do not recognize your usb moudem. So you should file a bug against your linux distributor and ask them to fix it. Sorry I cannot help you any further.

Comment: @AndrewFerrier,  Are you still looking for solution?

Answer (score 1):

I got it working by installing the usb-modeswitch package, and disabling autorun/automount in gconf-editor.

If that doesn't work, the only other (very inconvenient) way I saw was to boot with the modem plugged in; it worked then.... Good luck!